# Handle spring security authentication exceptions in ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, security, exception

I have Spring Boot application (2.0.2.RELEASE) with OAuth2.0 authorization.
I need to handle exception like following

> {
>       "error": "invalid_token",
>       "error_description": "Access token expired: eyJhbGc..." }
>
> {
>       "error": "unauthorized",
>       "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource" }

What i'm trying to do:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableResourceServer
public class CatalogServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CatalogServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }

public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!");
           response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. The "commence" method is not invokes.

Answer (score 2):

Every request to be authenticated using HTTP Basic authentication. If authentication fails, the configured AuthenticationEntryPoint will be used to retry the authentication process.

This problem not shared `AuthenticationEntryPoint` in securityConfig. that can be solve using with `@Component` and 
`@Autowired`.

Config:

**SpringSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;        

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }
```

**AuthtenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
           System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!");
           response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
        }
    }
```